# Test-path returning false when it should be true

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering why `test-path` is returning true and false with two statements, can anyone explain or suggest why?

```
$app2find = "Easeus"

### search ###
$appSearch = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
    Get-ItemProperty |
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match $app2find } |
            Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString

### search results ###
if (!$appSearch) { "No apps named like $app2find were found" }

### uninstall ###
ForEach ($app in $appSearch) {

    If ($app.UninstallString) {

        Test-Path $app.UninstallString
        Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\EaseUS Partition Master 10.5\unins000.exe"

        #& cmd /c $($app.UninstallString) /silent
    }
}
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Desired output:

```
True
True
```

many thanks

*EDIT

`$app.UninstallString` is a value in the registry that provides the way to uninstall a specific app. In this case exactly prints:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\EaseUS Partition Master 10.5\unins000.exe"
```

Comment: What is `$app.UninstallString` in that loop? Are you sure it is that value?

Comment: $app.UninstallString contains "C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\EaseUS Partition Master 10.5\unins000.exe"

Comment: Can you include exact output from that script with added lines that print that variable and your literal string?

Comment: $app.UnnistallString prints exactly the path I typed, thats why confused me, as said Matt seems like somekind of a quotation issue. Anyway thanks.

Comment: It prints the path with the quotes? Because that's **not** what you get if you do (for example) `$f="C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\EaseUS Partition Master 10.5\unins000.exe"` and then `$f` or `write-output $f`. Which is the point. The quotes are **in** the value. Which is why I asked to see **exactly** what printing it out (and printing out that literal string) showed. Since they would have differed in quotes and that would have told you the difference.

Comment: good point, and explains why is not the same get quoted data from the registry and set manually a string to a variable. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Etan has it right based on what you have shown us. Only thing we can figure is that `$app.UninstallString` does not contain an absolute path like you believe it does. Best guess is that the string is already quoted in the registry. `Test-Path` does not resolve strings with outer quotes.

Consider the following examples

```powershell
PS Z:\> test-path "c:\temp"
True

PS Z:\> test-path "'c:\temp'"
False

PS Z:\> test-path "'c:\temp'".Trim("'")
True
```

Perhaps you just need to trim quotes?

```powershell
Test-Path $app.UninstallString.Trim("'`"")
```

That should remove trailing and leading single and double quotes.

Comment: Yes in this case is a absolute path, seems like was a quotation issue and  Trim definetly fix it. Thx